# Spring boot pdf file java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, google-cloud-platform, attachment

In my spring boot application
I have kept MyPdfFile.pdf in resources folder and I am using below code to access and encode it

byte [] encodedByte = Base64.getEncoder().encode(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("MyPdfFile.pdf")));

Its working fine in local but after deploying in GCP I am getting below exception
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: MyPdfFile.pdf

Can any one help me on this How to solve. I am getting this exception only after deployment.

Comment: The file 'MyPdfFile.pdf' is not there on your GCP deployment environment, seems simple. The error message isn't lying.

Comment: I have kept the file in spring boot resources folder. Its working fine in local. After Deployment in gcp I am getting above error. How should I access pdf file from resources folder which works both in local and after deployment

Answer (score 0):

Your default path is CLASSPATH so if your pdf is at /user/1/2/3/4/5.pdf and your CLASSPATH is /user/1/2/3, type /4/5.pdf

Comment: I have kept my pdf file in spring boot resources folder, How can I access that pdf in class file while will work in local environment and after deployment in cloud?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know much about spring boot, but I have the same problem about CLASSPATH before